# PhoneGap PushPlugin installation - Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

While trying to install the PushPlugin for push notifications on PhoneGap

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

The Manual Installation process for Android required adding a few lines to the **AndroidManifest.xml** file which is not present in case of an HTML5 phonegap mobile application.

Should I add it in a certain directory?

Comment: is phonegap generating an apk file for you? If so you should have a manifest somewhere.

Comment: phonegap generates an apk file without the manifest

Comment: Where are you following instructions from to build your project? In the official [Getting Started With Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html) page for phonegap it indicates that there is a manifest file and it makes changes to it in the initial project example that they show...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: Apparently those instructions were for manual installation. You can simply install it by adding the following `<gap:plugin name="GenericPush" />` to your PhoneGap's  **config.xml** file.

I noticed that when I was comparing the Installation instructions and the plugin.xml file in the source code. Each installation step was found in the `plugin.xml` file.